# Why is the half-torus rigid?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, geometry, dg.differential-geometry, reference-request

The half-torus surface that results from slicing a torus like a bagel,
depicted below (left), is isometrically rigid.

     
[image: HalfTori]

I know this from a remark of Alexandrov in
[Mathematics: Its Content, Methods and Meaning](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486409163.html)
(Chapter 7. Curves and surfaces, p.101):

> For example, it has been shown that a surface in the form
>   of a circular trough (...), does not admit continuous deformations
>   (this explains, among other things, the familiar fact that a pail
>   with a curved rim is considerably stronger than one with
>   a plain rim) ...

He gives no hint of a proof, nor a reference.
Could someone supply either?
I would like to understand this enough to generalize to,
e.g., the bottom quarter of a torus (above, right), or to cross-sections
or sweep curves other than circles (ellipses, smooth convex curves, ...).
Are there general conditions known for a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with
boundary to be isometrically rigid, i.e., to admit no continuous deformation
that "preserves the length of all curves on the surface"
(to quote Alexandrov's definition)?

Comment: The rigidity of the punctured torus is listed as an open problem (number 13) by Ghomi here: people.math.gatech.edu/~ghomi/Papers/op.pdf . I guess either the list is wrong, or I am missing a distinction between things I don't understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've got a letter from Idjad Sabitov which answer the question completely. Here is a short extract from it:

1. half-torus has rigidity of second order (Rembs' theorem, see Е. Rembs. Verbiegungen hoeherer Ordnung  und ebene Flaechenrinnen. Math. Zeitschrift 36 (1932) or [Ефимов, УМН, 1948, т.3, вып.2, стр. 135](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/24e21b3682b6a64bfabeced47dff4a16/rm8695.pdf))
2. Any second order rigid surface does not admit *analytic deformation* (i.e., the deformation $h_t(u,v)$ which is analytic on $t$).
3. For the surfaces of revolution, the assumption of analyticity can be removed.

---

*Below is the best part of my original post. It contains an idea which was not used by Rembs.*

---

Let $h(u,v)$ be a small perturbation of the standard embedding;
$u\in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ and $v\in\mathbb S^1$.

Consider convex hull $K$ of $\mathop{\rm Im}h$
and look at the closed curve $\gamma_0$ which is formed by boundary of $\partial K\cap \mathop{\rm Im}h$.
I claim that $\gamma_0=h(0,{*})$ i.e. the Gauss curvature at points of $\gamma_0$ has to be $0$. 
Indeed since $\gamma_0$ lies on convex part, 
the Gauss curvature at the points of $\gamma_0$ has to be nonnegative. 
On the other hand $\gamma_0$ bounds a flat disc in $\partial K$;
therefore its integral intrinsic curvature (in $\partial K$ and in the torus) has to be $2{\cdot}\pi$.
If the Gauss curvature is positive at some point of $\gamma_0$ then total intrinsic curvature of $\gamma_0$ has to be $<2{\cdot}\pi$, a contradiction.

Note that if the asymptotic direction goes transversally to $\gamma_0$ at $\gamma_0(v)$ then $\gamma_v$ can not lie on the $\partial K$.
I.e., $\gamma_0=h(0,{*})$ is an asymptotic curve.

WLOG we can assume that the length of $\gamma_0=h(0,{*})$ is $2{\cdot}\pi$ and its intrinsic curvature is $\equiv 1$.
In the space $\gamma_0$ has to be a curve with constant curvature $1$ and it should be closed --- the only such curve is a flat circle.

Comment: That's great start, but I'm not so sure about the "easily from here" part. Maybe for you but not for me. Do you consider the positively curved part separately from the negatively curved part?

Comment: Ouch. If you can't finish it, it's definitely not easy.

Comment: Can one use that the equation on negative part is hyperbolic to get rigidity? If "yes" it would give an answer at least in analytic case.

Comment: I don't see offhand how. The curve separating positive from negative curvature is characteristic so standard uniqueness theorems for the initial value problem for a hyperbolic pde do not apply.

But maybe something from pogorelov's book can be used?

Comment: Why does $h\circ\gamma_0$ have curvature 1 in space?


Comment: I see it's the same statement, but why is it true? I think you can bend a small neighborhood so that it is no longer asymptotic...


Comment: I don't see why they bend in opposite direction. It is possible that the second fundamental form is positive in the two directions but $K<0$ due to a narrow sector where the form is negative.


Comment: Moreover, consider a generic (not isometric) perturbation of the torus. On it, the line separating $K>0$ from $K<0$ is not asymptotic. Otherwise it would have zero torsion and hence would be planar, but such things generically do not exist.


Comment: Looks very convincing now (the first part). (Btw, is it easy to prove that the added part of the convex hull boundary is simply connected?) But how to "apply the same argument" is a mystery.


Comment: Well, at least for small deformation it should be true.

Comment: Anton : could you elaborate a little on the "central circle in a cone" part ? Is it something like isoperimetry on the sphere that forces $n(\gamma_t)$ to be a circle there ? Thanks.

Comment: @BS, I know that this part is floppy,  but will not have time to make it better these days. 

Comment: @Anton: Thanks to writing to Sabitov! I will investigate Rembs.

Comment: What does second order rigidity mean?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: roughly speaking one cannot find any deformations which preserve distances up to 2nd order (if one writes the deformation as a power series in $\epsilon$ where it is the identity when $\epsilon=0$).  Likewise 1st order rigidity is a linearization of the problem.

Comment: I now have the Rembs paper.  For the record, here is a link: http://www.springerlink.com/content/t51345521u56u84l/

Comment: Here's an open access link to the Rembs paper http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN266833020_0036&DMDID=DMDLOG_0008 .  Also, I am not sure that what I said about 2nd order rigidity makes sense; one could reparametrize $\epsilon\mapsto\epsilon^2$ and convert a first-order distance preserving deformation to second-order, or higher. For rigidity of frameworks (the discrete setting), the definition of second-order rigid can be found in this paper by Connelly http://www.math.cornell.edu/~connelly/triangulated.pdf . My German is not good enough to see if this is what Rembs does.

Comment: Agreed. I'll leave the comment for now.

Answer (score 1):

For any surface patch with the first fundamental form
$$g(u,v) = \left[\begin{array}{cc} (c+a\cos{v})^2 & 0\\\\
0 & a^2\end{array}\right]$$
The Gauss and Codazzi Equations are

$$
\begin{align}
ac\cos(v)+a^2\cos^2(v)-h_{11}h_{22}+h_{12}^2&=0\\\\
h_{11,v} - h_{12,u} + \frac{a\sin(v)}{c+a\cos{v}}h_{11}+\frac{\sin(v)(c+a\cos(v))}{a}h_{22}&=0\\\\
h_{22,u} - h_{12,v} + \frac{a\sin(v)}{c+a\cos{v}}h_{12}&=0
\end{align}
$$
If we can show that the solution for the functions $h_{ij}$ is the same as that for the torus patch $(c+a\cos(v))\cos(u), (c+a\cos(v))\sin(u), a\sin(v))$, then we are done by uniqueness part of the Fundamental Theorem of Surfaces (patches with the same $g$ and $h$ differ only by a rigid motion).

Remark: If we make an overly strong assumption that $h$ is diagonal then this gives the result, but otherwise, as Deane comments, it is not immediately clear how/if we can prove the uniqueness of the $h_{ij}$ in the general case.

**Update:** Consider a particular local isometry of a patch on the torus that is small enough to not create any umbillic points. We can reparametrise in the neighbourhood of any non-umbillic point to a principal patch where **both** $g$ and $h$ are diagonal. The first fundamental form for the reparametrised isometric patch will have the form

$$g(u,v) = \left[\begin{array}{cc} \lambda(u,v)^2(c+a\cos{v})^2 & 0\\\\
0 & \mu(u,v)^2a^2\end{array}\right]$$

for known $\lambda,\mu$ and then the Codazzi equations are now a linear system for $h_{11},h_{22}$:
$$h_{11,v} = \frac12\partial_v(\lambda^2(c+a\cos{v})^2)(\frac{h_{11}}{\lambda^2(c+a\cos{v})^2} + \frac{h_{22}}{\mu^2a^2})$$

$$h_{22,u} = \frac12\partial_u(\mu^2a^2)(\frac{h_{11}}{\lambda^2(c+a\cos{v})^2} + \frac{h_{22}}{\mu^2a^2})$$

and the Gauss equation is 
$$h_{11}h_{22} = \lambda^2\mu^2a\cos(v)(c+a\cos(v)).$$

Comment: You've restated the question as a nonlinear system of PDE's for the second fundamental form. It's well known that for a surface, this system is elliptic where the Gauss curvature is positive and hyperbolic where it is negative. Proving uniqueness for such a system is, as far as I know, not easy. What's particularly troublesome is that the boundary between elliptic and hyperbolic (i.e., where the Gauss curvature vanishes) is a characteristic curve, so standard uniqueness theorems for boundary value problems do not apply. Do you have some ideas about how to do this?

Comment: I was mentally imagining switching out $\det{h}$ with $K\det{g}$ whenever it created trouble but that doesn't quite get the job done, does it.  Just as an idea, perhaps $h_{12}$ can be assumed zero at a single point via a rigid motion, and then controlled via a Gronwall-type inequality regardless of the elliptic/hyperbolic nature of the system, hence leaving only a linear system in the diagonal variables.