# Bending surfaces in Riemannian manifolds

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $S$ be an immersed surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (with the flat metric). We will call it flexible if there exists a smooth (or whatever regular) family of immersions $s_t: S\to \mathbb{R}^3$, such that each $s_t$ induces the same metric on $S$ and no $s_{t_1}$ and $s_{t_2}$ are related by an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (i.e. we rule out trivial deformations by one-parameter subgroups of ambient isometries).

1) Do there exist flexible smooth closed surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$? In the polyhedral world the answer is yes, with a well-known example of flexible polyhedron by Connelly.

Convex surfaces seem to be rigid, which should be a theorem of Alexandrov or Cauchy. Are there any other global criterions for rigidity/flexibility?

2) Is locally any surface flexible?

3) Can anybody give me an example of a rigid surface with boundary?

Comment: Regarding 3): It is relatively easy to set up boundary value problems for either certain positively curved or negatively curved surfaces that satisfy certain conditions (which would be satisfied on a sufficiently small neighborhood of a point) that imply infinitesimal rigidity. Using the implicit function theorem, these can be extended to local rigidity results (i.e., uniqueness within a set of sufficiently small deformations). There may be global rigidity results for the boundary value problem for positive curvature using results about Monge-Ampère equations.

Comment: Regarding 2): If no boundary conditions are imposed, then the theory of elliptic and hyperbolic PDEs with the implicit function theorem can be used to show that a surface is flexible in a sufficiently small neighborhood of a point with nonzero Gauss curvature

Comment: Regarding 1): I believe there is essentially nothing known outside the convex case. I have wondered whether it might be possible to smooth Connelly's polyhedral example by replacing the vertices by a smooth surface that flexes in the appropriate way.

Comment: 1 was previously asked here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1975/is-a-smooth-closed-surface-in-euclidean-3-space-rigid

Comment: Not an answer, but for non compact surfaces, see the notion of associated family for a minimal surface https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associate_family giving some of the most famous examples.  This idea generalizes to many symmetric spaces other than Euclidean space.

Comment: "Can anybody give me an example of a rigid surface with boundary?" See [Why is the half-torus rigid?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/77760/6094), but see [Anton Petrunin's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/77773/6094), which unfortunately seems to leave matters somewhat up in the air.

Comment: Regarding 2, it surprizes me that nobody mentioned that a piece of plane is flexible (you can roll it up into pieces of cylinders or revolution cones).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard reference, where the state of the art concerning all of your questions is found:

> Q. Han, J.-X. Hong, **Isometric Embedding of Riemannian Manifolds in Euclidean Spaces,** Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R. I., Math. Surveys and Monographs, vol. 130, 2006.

There is still no proof that every compact smooth embedded surface in 3-dimensional Euclidean space is rigid. Michael T. Anderson recently [produced](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.3202) a proof, but a flaw emerged.

The local flexibility of any smooth surface with nonzero or nonnegative Gauss curvature is, I believe, a straightforward consequence of the results in Han and Hong, although they don't state it explicitly.

Han and Hong prove (theorem 8.1.2) that any smooth closed surface, with nonnegative Gauss curvature vanishing on a nowhere dense set, is rigid.

Another very important work, *[Open problems in geometry of curves and surfaces](http://people.math.gatech.edu/%7Eghomi/Papers/op.pdf)* (and a very nice one to read) on these questions is the unpublished manuscript of Mohammed Ghomi, which sums up many of the open questions on curves and surfaces in Euclidean space, and particularly the flexibility questions, with a thoughtful collection of references.

Rigidity of the top half of a torus is discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/77760/why-is-the-half-torus-rigid?rq=1), but perhaps without a complete proof having become clear yet.